# Calculation of angular frequency and wave vector from time series data using minimum variance method

Tags: vectors, statistics

Suppose, I have 20 data for the velocity components Vx, Vy and Vz with 5 minutes interval of time, how to find the angular frequency and wave vector using minimum variance method for those data? What is the Physics/Mathematics behind that? Thanks!

What else method we can follow to find the angular frequency and wave vector using those time series data?

Actually, I don't understand the basic.

I request a clear explanation so that I can understand the basic. Thanks!